# apache camel - add message alert to deadletter queue

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq, alerts

```
String queueA = "rabbitmq://host:5672/queue-a.exchange?queue=queue-a.exchange..etc

from(queueA)
  .routeId("idForQueueA")
  .onException(Exception.class)
    .maximumRedeliveries(0)
    // .processRef("sendEmailAlert")  * not sure this belongs here*
    .to(deadLetterQueueA)
    .useOriginalMessage()
  .end()
    .processRef("dataProcessing")
    .processRef("dataExporting")
  .end();
```

> Explaining the code above:

Messages are taken from queueA. Upon various processes being successful the message is consumed.  If it fails its added to the dead letter queue "deadLetterQueueA".  This all works ok.

My question is

> When messages arrive in the deadletter queue I want to add alerts so we know to do something about it...  How could I to add an email alert when a message arrives in the dead letter queue.  I dont want to lose the original message if the alert fails - nor do I want the alert to consume the message.

---

My thoughts are.. I would need to split the message on an exception so its sent to two different queues?  One for the alert which then sends out an email alert and then consumes itself. Then one for the dead letter queue that just sites  there?  However I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: Use a monitoring tool like Zabbix to check the queue depth of your dead-letter queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split a message to go to multiple endpoints using a `multicast` (details [here](http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html)):

```
.useOriginalMessage().multicast().to(deadLetterQueueA, "smtp://username@host:port?options")
```

This uses the camel mail component endpoints described [here](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html).  Alternatively, you can continue processing the message after the `to`.  So something like:

```
.useOriginalMessage()
.to(deadLetterQueueA)
.transform().simple("Hi <name>, there has been an error on the object ${body.toString}")
.to("smtp://username@host:port?options")
```

If you had multiple recipients, you could use a [recipients list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html)

```
public class EmailListBean {
    @RecipientList
    public String[] emails() {
        return new String[] {"smtp://joe@host:port?options",
                "smtp://fred@host:port?options"};
    }
}

.useOriginalMessage()
.to(deadLetterQueueA)
.transform().simple("...")
.bean(EmailListBean.class)
```

Be careful of using JMS queues to store messages while waiting for a human to action them.  I don't know what sort of message traffic you're getting.  I'm assuming if you want to send an email for every failure, it's not a lot.  But I would normally be wary of this sort of thing, and chose to use logging or database persistence to store the results of errors, and only use a JMS error queue to notify other processes or consumers of the error or to schedule a re-try.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can do this , but based on your message volume you might not want to send email on every failed message.

You can use the solution provided by AndyN , or you can use the Advisory Topics ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDLQd.Queue.* , whenever a message gets in to the DLQ the enqueue count of the topic will increase by 1 . By monitoring the Queue Depth you might now be able to send a mail to based on the number of the errors that ocurred.

If you want to do it at the producer end. You can use any one of the solutions provided by AndyN